# Why is the FIFA Head-to-Head Season Squad update crashing for me?

Tags: fifa-12

when I play FIFA Head-to-Head season, my game sometimes gives me the old squads, then kicks me after searching for a game.This started to happen recently and is really draining my battery!Can anyone please help me? Can you help me find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on my Xbox 360, to resolve it I deleted the team file (can't remember the exact name of the file) from my Xbox. It can be found under Settings -> Storage -> Hard drive -> Fifa 12. The file is named something like Online squads or Online teams, delete it, boot Fifa up again and a new file will be downloaded when you try to play online.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to EA's update servers not working properly.

When this happens, a workaround is to go back to the main screen of FIFA. Reentering head to head menu should force a reload.